# Need advise on how to POST to PHP correctly with Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

So, I am currently trying to use PHP (still new to PHP) with Angular, and would like some advise so I can write good clean code.

Basically, I am trying to get analytics from an third-party API, but first I must retrieve a token with my username + password, and then after I receive the token, I must then call another URL and add that token in the parameter.

First, in my controller - *I'll add my $http call in my services later*

```
var username = 'test';
var pass = 'test password';

$http({
    url: 'http://example/stats.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param({ 
        "user_id": username,
        "pass" : pass
    }),
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data.tokenResponse.tokenId);
    // Here I get back that token Id

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

In my PHP Script, I pass the user_id & pass, and then call the API and echo back the $data.

```
$username = $_POST['user_id'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$data = 
file_get_contents('https://examplestats.com/rest/auth/json?login='.$username.'&password='.$password.'');
echo str_replace("\\","", $data);
```

In return I get,

```
Object
tokenResponse: Object
tokenId: "96996a53-6464-42d6-9726-47be0971f323"
universe: Array[3]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Now that I have the Token, I must get the analytics. The third party states that I must pass the token in the url as a parameter i.e

example.com/rest/data/json?tokenId=**96996a53-6464-42d6-9726-47be0971f323**&indicator=Analytics

Now the question is, how can I call stats.php just one time and retrieve the data? At the moment, I could create another php file and do the same process, but then I would be repeating code.  In the meantime, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: is the `$data` you obtain in your PHP script the token?

Comment: I just edited my post and added what my response is - Object / tokenResponse / tokenId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode` in your PHP script to get the tokenID and make another request:

```
$username = $_POST['user_id'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$data = 
file_get_contents('https://examplestats.com/rest/auth/json?login='.$username.'&password='.$password.'');
$data = json_decode($data);
$analytics = file_get_contents('https://examplestats.com/rest/data/json?tokenId=' . $data->tokenResponse->tokenId . '&indicator=Analytics');
echo str_replace("\\","", $analytics);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user1950929, this has answered my question.  I better start learning more about PHP!

Comment: no problem, if you want to learn more about PHP, there is a good online course at http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/php